# i want to add div after input if (hover or focus) then if i clicked on the new div let the div displayed up to click on another element or focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have form including 2 type of information first type is new data and the second type comes from the database "this type defined by attribute preDefined" 
i want to display search icon after input that have attribute preDefined only if i focus or hover on the input "this icon i use it to display new modal to select the data from database" so if i clicked on the icont button let the icon displayed if i clicked on another let the icon removed

this is the Jquery function

```
     $('input').each(function(){
       if ($(this).attr('preDefined') === 'preDefined') {
         $(this).focus(function(){
           $(this).after(
           '<button type="button" class="preDefinedSearch" id="preDefinedSearch" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>'
           );
         })
         .blur(
           jQuery('#preDefinedSearch').click(function(){
              $(this).data('clicked', true);
            }));
            if(jQuery('#preDefinedSearch').data('clicked')) {

                //clicked element, do-some-stuff
            }
            else {
              $("#preDefinedSearch").remove();
            }

         $(this).hover(function(){
           $(this).after(
             '<button type="button" class="preDefinedSearch" id="preDefinedSearch" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>'
           );
         },
         function(){
           $("#preDefinedSearch").remove();
         })
       }

     });
```

this is my First code it works fine to add and remove the button but the problem when i click on the button the button removed and the modal not opened

```
       // add search div pre define fields
       $('input').each(function(){
         if ($(this).attr('preDefined') === 'preDefined') {
           // NOTE: add button on focus of preDefined input
           $(this).focus(function(){
             $(this).after(
               '<button type="button" class="preDefinedSearch" id="preDefinedSearch" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>'
             );
           })
           // NOTE: remove button if no focus of preDefined input
           .blur(function(){
             $("#preDefinedSearch").remove();
           });
         }
       });
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a read of these articles from the JQuery API docs. .focus() and .blur() can be used to display or remove elements from the DOM when a certain element has been clicked into or clicked out of.

https://api.jquery.com/focus/

https://api.jquery.com/blur/

Comment: if i want to add and remove only it's ok it work good but i want after add element if i clicked on it lit this new element displayed "don't remove it" @PumpkinBreath